# Deploy a scanned container from Jenkins in to Kubernetes

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, appharbor

I am trying to create a job in jenkins that picks up a recently scanned image from a harbor repository and deploys it into an existing kubernetes cluster.

I am working on a offline server and quite new to Jenkins.

What would be the best way to do this? Would I need to use a pipeline or just a jenkins freestyle project?

Thanks

Comment: This isn't really worthy of an answer, hence the comment - but I've got this working using Octopus deploy (which is triggered by Jenkins), a linux machine (as my octopus target) and a whole bunch of bash scripting. They (Octopus Deploy team) are currently working on native kubernates support, so it should be possible to do this in the near future without the linux machine/bash script step.

Comment: I have a pipeline that does this, except with Artifactory for the repo and JFrog/Qualys scans instead of Harbor. Also, it builds, validates, and pushes the image to the repo in addition to the other steps. So it is definitely possible, but tougher with Harbor due to the lack of a native Jenkins plugin and DSL (as far as I know anyway). Doing this with freestyle sounds like a nightmare. This can all be done quite simply in a Jenkinsfile.

Comment: Something I am testing now. This runs as a simple Jenkins job; stage('Deploy to Kubernetes') {
    
  sh "kubectl apply -f hello-app.yaml --kubeconfig=/kubernetes/config/admin.conf"
  
  sleep 15

}